# Last 2 numbers of the current year

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the last 2 numbers of the current year with carbon on Laravel.

I tried this in my controller:

```php
$year = Carbon::now()->year; // ok i got 2017
```

I would like to get just "17". I checked carbon's documentation for the `Carbon::createFromFormat` function, but I don't know the method to get only the last 2 numbers. As the function format in DateTime from PHP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this and you get 17:

```
Carbon::now()->format('y')
```

use **format()** when you want formatting Carbon date

Comment: Now with latest versions of Laravel you can use the carbon helper and do now()->format('y')